# How to upload funds in Drupal website?

Tags: ubercart, commerce

I want to upload funds in my Drupal website using stripe and paypal methods. I am not able to find sub module in ubercart which can help me

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "uploading funds"? Drupal is in no way an accounting application, and unless you're a bank, you can't really store money on your server anyway.

Comment: You can say that i want users to purchase points

Answer (score 0):

Ubercart comes with paypal options for payment, there is a Stripe module under development, but you would have to wait, or use the dev version. (https://drupal.org/project/stripe)